# Nested if statements keep producing a "False" statement in the cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to nest the following if statements PART ONE is: `=IF(ISBLANK(E2),"",IF((TODAY()-$A2)>=7,IF(REGEXMATCH($I2,"ORDERED|ordered|order number|PO#|PO|purchase order|po|p.o"),"Request Ordered",$E2&"  Requested Not Ordered"),""))` based upon a number of conditions: 1st cell e2 is populated then the date in a2 must be greater than or equal to 7days. If these conditions are met then I need to combine this additional if condition in the nest: `=IF(ISBLANK(J3),"Request Ordered","Request Order Complete")` However, when I combine them I get the word false in cell m2) where I need to make this work.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ifs()`, like this:

```
=ifs( 
  isblank(E2), 
    iferror(1/0), 
  today() - $A2 < 7, 
    iferror(1/0), 
  regexmatch($I2, "(?i)ordered|order number|purchase order|p.o|\bpo\b"), 
    if( isblank(J3), "Request Ordered", "Request Order Complete" ), 
  true, 
    $E2 & " Requested Not Ordered" 
)
```

Comment: I am using Google sheets. Will this formula work there?

Comment: Yes. It is a Google Sheets formula.